# Crosslink to specific element in XML from HTML file via "Anchor"

Tags: html, xml

I have a HTML file and a XML file that i can't modify.
I can't use javascript, just bare-metal HTML.

XML example:

```
<bookstore>
  <book category="children">
    <title>Harry Potter</title>
    <author>J K. Rowling</author>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book category="web">
    <title>Learning XML</title>
    <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
    <year>2003</year>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

**I want to have a clickable link in the HTML file that opens the XML file in a new tab and scrolls down to the position of the XML element with a matching attribute similar to an HTML Anchor.**

**As an example** let's say I want to create a link from the HTML file to the position of the XML element "book" with the attribute category="web".

Is this possible? I only found links between XML documents, and nothing about linking in this HTML Anchor style to XML.

Comment: *"I want to create a link from the HTML file to the position of the XML element with a matching attribute similar to an HTML Anchor."* - That's a lot more vague than you probably assume. Link to a position... how? Like, you want to open the XML in a browser tab and it should scroll down automatically? I don't think that will be possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Tomalak. That is exactly what i want to do. I archieved opening the XML in a new tab, but i can't get the scrolling working

Comment: And you never will, that's simply not possible. Any other options?

Comment: Another option would be e.g. this: An XSLT stylesheet is included in the XML file. It transforms the XML into nicely formatted HTML (the browser does that automatically when loading the XML). The resulting HTML contains some Javascript that scrolls down the page. From your page you could make links like this: `<a href="books.xml#web">`. The browser sees the `books.xml` part and loads the XML, the XSLT gets applied automatically, the JavaScript sees the `web` part and figures out where to scroll. It's a bit roundabout, but it can work. And it's the best idea I have for this situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for your answers, i will try this.

Comment: I can help with this, that's why I'm suggested it. I just don't know if it's feasible for your situation. Or maybe your situation can be changed so a better solution becomes available. Can you tell me a bit more context: Why linking to a bare-bones XML document? Why no Javascript? Who is the target audience, what's the use case?